# How to connect parameter from function to a call to action in UI?

Tags: flutter

Hello I try to make full migraion in nullsafty, but now I have an error between my function and the call of my function in the UI

Before upgrade all this code worked great
Here is my old function

```
    void goToNewItemView() async {

    final slider= await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => NewTodo(),
    ).then((title){
      if(title != null) {
        addItem(Todo_bis(title: title));
        _saveData();
      }
    }
   );
  }
```

Here is my UI

```
             Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child :  new RawMaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  goToNewItemView();
                },
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color:  Color(0xffff9a7b),
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                shape: new CircleBorder(),
                elevation: 4.0,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
            )
```

Here is the State full Widget call by the function goToNewItemView() and call by showDialog

```
class NewTodo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Todo item;

  NewTodo({this.item });

  @override
  _NewTodoState createState() => _NewTodoState();
}

class _NewTodoState extends State<NewTodo> {
...
 }
```

after flutter upgrade I have somes errors
First I add `required this.item`  to be compatible nullsafety in NewTodo statefull Widget
After I have error of missing argument on my function goToNewItemView() so I add goToNewItemView(item) and NewTodo(item:item),
But after that I have error in the UI section goToNewItemView(); need an arguement but I do'nt know what ?

If I let with no argument goToNewItemView(); I have error : 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

I don't know what argument add, I tried

```
goToNewItemView(item);
goToNewItemView(item: item);
```

but always error

Here is my function after upgrade

```
    void goToNewItemView(item) async {

    final slider= await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => NewTodo(item:item),
    ).then((title){
      if(title != null) {
        addItem(Todo_bis(title: title));
        _saveData();
      }
    }
   );
  }
```

Here is my UI

```
             Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child :  new RawMaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  goToNewItemView();
                },
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color:  Color(0xffff9a7b),
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                shape: new CircleBorder(),
                elevation: 4.0,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
            )
```

Here is the State full Widget call by the function goToNewItemView(item) and call by showDialog

```
class NewTodo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Todo item;

  NewTodo({required this.item });

  @override
  _NewTodoState createState() => _NewTodoState();
}

class _NewTodoState extends State<NewTodo> {
...
 }
```

I found the soution, just convert  final Todo item; to  final Todo? item;  like that I can remove required from required this.item and all the reste no need parameters

Comment: show the error too

Comment: Can you add the error message that you are getting to the question, since we cannot run your code as it is, it is hard to determine where the error is.

Comment: I found the soution, just convert  final Todo item; to  final Todo? item;  like that I can remove required from required this.item and all the reste no need parameters

Answer (score 0):

The error is not relative to null safety.

The parameter is not optional, so you need to specify it:

```
goToNewItemView(the_item_to_pass)
```

If it doesn't work then there is another error.
Or maybe it refers to these functions:

```
    addItem(Todo_bis(title: title));
    _saveData();
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know what add in the (), I upgrade my post with the staful widget that I call.

Comment: I have explain the complet problem with the chronologie

Comment: null safety force me to add required this.item in the statefull widget. Because of this, I'm forced to add item argument to my function goToNewItemView(), and after I need to add an argument to goToNewItemView in the UI section, but I don't know what I need to add ?